# Unable to sign security tokens with certificate in WIF scenario

Tags: wcf, x509certificate, wif, makecert

I'm trying to implement a custom STS for a WIF scenario I'm investigating, but it's failing. It's failing when trying to obtain the private key from the certificate used to sign the tokens. I create the STS with the following configuration:

```
var signingCert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\<path>\MySigningCertificate.pfx");
var config
    = new SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration()
    {
        DisableWsdl = true,
        TokenIssuerName = "Tribold",
        SecurityTokenService = typeof(TriboldSecurityTokenService),
        SigningCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials(signingCert),
        CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom,
        CertificateValidator = new CertificateValidator()
    };
```

However, with WCF diagnostic logging configured, I get the following message in the Service Trace Viewer:

`The private key is not present in the X.509 certificate.`

This appears to be logged as the code comes out of my custom STS (i.e., after calling `GetOutputClaimsIdentity(...)` on my custom STS class, and therefore I can only assume that it's now trying to sign the issued security token and failing because it can't obtain a private key to do so.

The private key appears to be present on the loaded certificate:

```
Debug.Assert(signingCert.HasPrivateKey == true);
```

but it fails later on. I'm having no luck resolving this, please help!

Comment: Just to confirm: When you look at the certificate properties with the mmc certificate snap-in does it say "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate"?

Comment: @nzpcmad - Yes, the certificate has a padlock on it, and the message also appears when you double click the certificate and view it's details. I imported the .PFX files that were created from the certificates.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like thread ["cant use .pfx file for X.509 certificates"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Geneva/thread/2b2681af-838e-4f22-84fa-b5494b9dcc02) in the Geneva (= AD FS 2.0) forums covers the same problem which you report.  So the resolution reported there might work, which is "specifying the `X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet` flag when initiating the `X509Certificate2` object".

Comment: I came across that forum post and tried it. It didn't work and still gave me the "private key is not present" error. So frustrating. I've disabled the need to encrypt the security tokens for the time being (relying on message security), and it gets me onto the next error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if you didn't have to specify a password when opening a PFX file. X509Certificate2 [has overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148420.aspx) that take a password in the form of a string or a SecureString.

Comment: I've tried certificates with and without password protected private keys - both producing the same error.